# How to start work with omp4j

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have some time consuming calculation in my program, so i decided to use parallel computing. Internet search lead me to omp4j, but i struggling with its tutorial.
[omp4j download page](http://www.omp4j.org/download)

Tutorial says:

1. Make sure that a common JDK is installed (OracleJDK 7/8 or OpenJDK
   6/7)
2. Download one of the listed JARs below (latest version suggested)
3. Create a shell alias for omp4j in form of java -jar
4. Learn how to use omp4j in the tutorial!

command

> java -jar omp4j-1.2.jar

says:"No files passed" and giving nullpointerexception in main class. On passing any file it gives only exception.
Can somebody give a solution to my problem? Or maybe you know a better and simple way to parallel computing?

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
java -jar omp4j-1.2.jar Test.java
java Test
```

Comment: It's nice that you show the right way, but better if you explain a little why the right way is right.